# How to convert a column of age counts into a set useful for statistics?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a column of ages and a column of the count of those ages. I need these to be transformed into a set that I can run statistical functions like average on. For example:

| Age | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | 2 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 17 | 3 |

This needs to become (14,14,16,17,17,17) so that I could use =average or =stddev more easily on it. I have figured out a workaround to calculate average based off the formula but am stuck on standard deviation. There is probably a simple solution but I'm unable to find it on google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(SUM(B2:B4)),SCAN(0,B2:B4,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),A2:A4,,1)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(CONCAT(REPT(A2:A4&" ",B2:B4))),," ")/1
```

---

**Edit:** 3/28/2024

• Using `TOCOL()` & `SEQUENCE()` functions, bit shorter way:

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(A1:A4/(SEQUENCE(,MAX(B1:B4))<=B1:B4),2)
```

---

**Note:** The above won't work with `Text` values, for that a bit change refer below:

[image]

---

```
=TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(,MAX(B1:B4))<=B1:B4,A1:A4),2)
```

---