# Array with repeating text

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, repeat

I am trying to create an array where certain text values are repeated a certain number of times.

For example, the text in row 18 would repeat n number of times where n is in row 19.

[image: excel table]

Ive tried several things like let and sequence with no luck.

```
=LET(in,I18,rep,I19,s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)*rep,1,0),INDEX(in,QUOTIENT(E6s,rep)+1))
```

---

```
=TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(I18,SEQUENCE(I19,1,1,0)))
```

---

These both repeat one cell but the correct number of times but I need to add in the other columns.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74571541/9758194) be helpful, if not a near duplicate?

Comment: Similar question: **[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77865969/8162520)** only in this one the data is horizontal while the one i have shared is vertical. Please do research too many similar question on one topic.

Comment: And here is one more **[Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77460091/8162520)** minor changes. like from `ROWS()` to be changed to `COLUMNS()` .

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way without using `LAMBDA()` helper:

### [image]

```
=TOCOL(IFS(SEQUENCE(MAX(A2:J2))<=A2:J2,A1:J1),2,1)
```

---

And here is using `LAMBDA()` helper `MAKEARRAY()` version:

```
=LET(
     α, A1:J1,
     φ, A2:J2,
     TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(COLUMNS(α),MAX(φ),LAMBDA(δ,ε,
     IF(ε<=INDEX(φ,δ),INDEX(α,δ),p))),2))
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using Reduce:

```
=LET(names,I18:R18,
rpts,I19:R19,
REDUCE("Array",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(names)),
 LAMBDA(a,c,IF(INDEX(rpts,c)=0,a,VSTACK(a,IF(SEQUENCE(INDEX(rpts,c)),INDEX(names,c)))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Repeat Columns a Given Number of Times

- The following is based on [Mayukh Bhattacharya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77332255) to *"How to convert a column of age counts into a set useful for statistics?"* which covers repeating a row. (What a coincidence: I was just studying it.)

---

In `A17` (Basic):

```
=LET(data,A1:H3,repeat_rows,{1;3},count_row,2,get_cols,0,
    d,FILTER(data,CHOOSEROWS(data,count_row)>0),
    sr,CHOOSEROWS(d,repeat_rows),
    slr,CHOOSEROWS(d,count_row),
    sl,SCAN(0,slr,LAMBDA(sc,c,sc+c)),
    dl,SEQUENCE(SUM(slr)),
    si,XMATCH(dl,sl,1),
    drs,CHOOSECOLS(sr,si),
    dr,IF(get_cols,TRANSPOSE(drs),drs),
    dr)
```

In `A6` (Transposed): replace `get_cols,0,` with `get_cols,1,`)

In `D6` (The Requirement): additionally replace `A1:H3` with `A1:H2` and `{1;3}` with `{1}` or `1`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative with LAMBDA, EXPAND and FILTER.

```
=LET(z,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C1)),LAMBDA(u,v,VSTACK(u,IFERROR(IFNA(EXPAND(INDEX(A1:C1,,v),INDEX(A2:C2,,v)),INDEX(A1:C1,,v)),{""})))),1),FILTER(z,LEN(z)>0))
```

[image: Array with repeating text]